# Multiselect - reinitialize data after already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a multi-select box, using the 'Fast Select' plugin.  I am loading the data via an Ajax call, and the options are loaded fine.  When I try to refresh the call, to get new data, no items are being removed and no new items are being added.  I can see the Ajax calls are successful and they are returning the new data no problem.

It is as if once the data is in there, it won't remove items via code nor add new items. Any ideas on what I could do?

Here is the function that populates the list successfully the first time:

```
        function FillMachines() {
        let dropdown = $('#RptProductionStatusParam_Machine');
        var jobNum = $('#RptProductionStatusParam_JobDropDown').val();
        dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        const url = '/Reports/GetMachinesByJob';
        $.getJSON(url,
            {
                jobNum: jobNum
            },
            function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, machine) {
                dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', machine.Id).text(machine.LocationName));
            })
        });
    }
```

Here is how I am creating the multiselect:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RptProductionStatusParam.Machine, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "multipleSelect", @multiple = "multiple"})
```

Comment: How are you refreshing the data?

Comment: By calling FillMachines() again, this approach works for a regular drop down but does not seem to work for this 'Fast Select' plugin

Comment: What is the "Fast Select" plugin? Could be you need to run some update method after the first call.